# How to fix NoReverseMatch in django?

Tags: django

**Here is the detail error：**
    NoReverseMatch at /accounts/login/

```
Reverse for 'detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['users/(?P<username>
[^/]+)/$']

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://192.168.109.138:8000/accounts/login/
Django Version:     2.1.7
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    

Reverse for 'detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['users/(?P<username>
[^/]+)/$']
```

**the part of views.py in users app:**

```
class UserUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):

model = User
fields = ["nickname", "job_title", "introduction", "picture", "location", "personal_url",
          "weibo", "zhihu", "github", "linkedin"]
template_name = "users/user_form.html"

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse("users:detail", kwargs={"username": self.request.user.username})

def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    return self.request.user
```

I can not figure out how the reverse() function work and what are the useages of args and kwargs

**the users\urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from zhuri02.users import views


app_name = "users"
urlpatterns = [
path("update/", views.UserUpdateView.as_view(), name="update"),
path("<username>/", views.UserDetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),
]
```

**the config\urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("users/", include("zhuri02.users.urls", namespace="users")),
    path("accounts/", include("allauth.urls")),
# Your stuff: custom urls includes go here
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I'm not sure how to figure this error,please do help,thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like the error is generated somwhere else. Since you do not pass any parameters. So a `{% url "users:dtail" %}` or `reverse("users:detail")`.

Comment: Note, what if someone uses username="update"? Check your urlpatterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing in your `urls.py, so instead of this:

```
path("<username>/", views.UserDetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),
```

you have this. Notice the type `slug`

```
path('<slug:username>/', views.UserDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

There are a few things you can use instead `slug`, such as `str`, `int` and so on.

More info here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#path-converters